# Como ignorar primeira <tr> na pesquisa em jquery.datatables?

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Tenho uma tabela onde o primeiro `<tr>` eu coloco uma imagem, se que quando vou pesquisar vem junto o nome da imagem.

Por exemplo: na primeira linha da tabela a `img` tem o nome de `head.png` e o resto da linha não tem a letra `p`.

Só que quando coloco para pesquisar "p" a pesquisa me mostra a primeira linha.

Mas quando coloco pelo menos uma linha sem `img` ele consegue pesquisar.

Comment: Deve ter algum problema no seu código, porque a busca só procura por texto e ignora tags e o que tem dentro delas.

Comment: Pois é mais eu não sei onde é. quando pesquiso por head.png ele pesquisa todos que tem a imagem.

Comment: Aí teria que mostrar seu código pra que possamos tentar reproduzir o problema.

Comment: codigo html ou .js?

Comment: Cria um jsfiddle de posta lá o html e o js

Answer (score -1):

### Atualização 24/12/2017

Você pode controlar o que é pesquisado (e até o que é ordenado) através da opção [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).

No caso, deve-se passar uma função e tratar quando segundo parâmetro `type` ter o conteúdo `filter`. O quarto parâmetro `meta` pode ajudar a determinar qual é a linha sem depender de algum dado adicional na tabela, pois `meta.row` é o índice da linha.

Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
    if (type == "filter" && meta.row == 0)
        return "Texto customizado"; //aqui fica a seu critério o valor que será pesquisado

    return data;
}
```

### Resposta original

Você pode controlar o que é pesquisado (e até o que é ordenado) através da opção [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).

No caso, deve-se passar uma função e tratar quando segundo parâmetro `type` ter o conteúdo `filter`. Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
render: function (data, type) {
    if (type == "display")
        return data;
    else if (type == "filter")
        return "Texto customizado";
}
```

Comment: Mais no caso como faço para ignorar a primeira `<tr>`? não entendi ainda.

Comment: Para a primeira linha, você pode retornar `undefined` quando o tipo do render é `filter`, assim ele não é incluído na pesquisa.

Comment: pode editar a resposta?

Comment: Resposta atualizada

Comment: Como assim o valor que será pesquisado?

Comment: Você pode ter um valor específico para pesquisa. Tive um caso parecido em um projeto, onde havia uma coluna que indicava se o registro estava válido ou inválido, porém havia uma imagem para indicar isso. Nesta coluna, quando o tipo era `display` era retornado o html da imagem, quando era `filter` era retornado "válido" ou "inválido". Assim conseguimos exibir uma coisa e pesquisar outra.

Answer (score -3):

Você pode experimentar fazer dessa maneira:

```js
$('#idTabela').DataTable({

  "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
      if ( data[0] == "Conteúdo celula" ) {
        $(row).addClass( 'd-none' );
      }
  }

})
```